# Kinect not recognized with openni.launch

Tags: kinect, openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am currently using two different computers to work with my robot, both of them are on ROS Groovy.
I tried to use the Kinect with those computers using "roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch", but it works on one of the computers but not the other one. The only difference between the two computers is that I did some updates on the one that is not working well.
The error message I get is : "No device connected"

I read some other questions about this problem, so my Kinect is connected on a USB 2.0, and I tried "rmmod -f gspca_kinect" but it's not working.

I read those questions :
http://answers.ros.org/question/60562/ubuntu-12042-and-openni_launch-not-detecting-kinect-after-update/

http://answers.ros.org/question/60576/microsoft-kinect-not-connected/

But it seems that nobody found a solution to the problem for the moment.

Caroline

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60766/kinect-not-recognized-with-openni.launch/) by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 395 on 2013-04-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-04-15**:
Have you installed the old NITE 1.5.2 ? You should first use the ./uninstall, then the ./install.
Which Ubuntu are you on ? If 12.10, USB 3.0 is not a problem, otherwise it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution was to reinstall PrimeSense Sensor :
the explanation was given here http://answers.ros.org/question/60562/ubuntu-12042-and-openni_launch-not-detecting-kinect-after-update/

As for djtubig-malicex in this post, I had the same version but it was not working, in the version in the link given it works.

---

Originally posted by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) with karma: 395 on 2013-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1